# Reading 4-20ma transmitter stm32 adc

Tags: stm32, adc

I try to use 4-20 ma pressure transmitter
With stm32 internal adc
Problem reading is flacuating too much I have to take average for 128-256 reading to take stable reading
Is that normal solution or there is other way to filter data and transmitter signal ??

Comment: Any code/schematics?

Comment: Code is simple adc code to read channel  I used residtor simulatir to confirm problem from transmitter side then i add capacitor 100 uf parrell to current resistor flutuation reduced too much but still exist so i reduced filter count than before

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons can affect the reading stability. Basically grounding, PCB layout, input cables, noise on the uController supply pins, input RC filter, the ADC code...
I have a similar application using a current resistor of 162R from input connector to the same ground of the ADC input. Than a series resistor of 22k and a ceramic capacitor of 47nF to ground, placed close to the ADC pin.
With that I take 10 ADC measures and make an average. Signal is stable.
Please, share your code and circuit diagram...